# Get the title and array of images from a remote URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im looking for a way to fetch remote title and an array of the images on the remote page in rails

Any out there that knows how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just use a library like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open 'http://www.example.com')
doc.css('img') # => A collection of img nodes
```

Refer to the documentation for more details.